# Integration over variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to take the integration of 1/x over v0 and vt. I want it to output: `Ln(v0 / vt)` or at least `Ln(v0) - Ln(vt)`. I tried using `Integrate` but it's taking a really long time to run and I don't think it's right. How would I achieve this in mathematica? Here's what I tried:

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}]
```

I want to do this so I can ultimately solve for v0.

Edit: I was able to do this using:

```
in = Integrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}, Assumptions -> 0 < v0 <= vt]
```

Now I want to set `in` equals to `g / v0` and solve for `vt`, which should give me:

```
vt = v0 E^(g / v0)
```

How would I achieve this? I tried using Solve and Reduce but they are giving me some strange answers.

Comment: `Integrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}, Assumptions -> 0 < v0 <= vt]`. Remember that *Mathematica* assumes that all variables are complex if not told otherwise. Given your expected result, I think you are implicitly making the assumption that $v_0$ and $v_t$ are real, which needs to be made explicit. Also, check your anticipated result: I suspect that it should really be $\log(v_t/v_0)$ given your integration domain.

Comment: Thank you that worked. However I want to solve for v0 when I set the entire thing equal to `g / v0`. How would I do that? I tried using Solve and Reduce and they gave me some weird answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Solve[Integrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}, Assumptions -> 0 < v0 <= vt] == g/v0, v0]

(* Out: {{v0 -> -(g/ProductLog[-(g/vt)])}} *)
```

Or perhaps with a few more assumptions, and heeding `Solve`'s suggestion to use `Reduce`, which would get us a more complete complete answer including "special cases" (i.e. solutions that are valid only for *some* values of the parameters, rather than for *all*):

```
Reduce[
  {
   Integrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}, Assumptions -> 0 < v0 <= vt] == g/v0, 
   g > 0, v0 >= 0, vt >= 0
  }, 
  v0, Reals
]

(* Out: 
   g > 0 && vt >= E g && (v0 == E^ProductLog[-(g/vt)] vt || 
   v0 == E^ProductLog[-1, -(g/vt)] vt)
*)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: Yes I've been out. Sorry!

Comment: @Ccyan thank you for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output to be a function of v0 and vt, you do not need necessarily to do explicit symbolic integration. I hope this might help:

```
Integration[v0_?NumberQ, vt_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[1/x, {x, v0, vt}]
Integration[5, 3]
```

My output is -0.510826